# How to remove rows in a Pandas Dataframe that are text but not integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I remove the rows in a pandas dataframe that are text while keeping the rows that are integers? See example below removing text from **Column1** only:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Anything | 13 |
| Something | More |
| 1 | Text |
| -15 | 13333 |
| More Text | 67 |
| 354 | Test |

**Expected Result:**

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Text |
| -15 | 13333 |
| 354 | Test |

Comment: `df[pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'], errors='coerce').notna()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
(df.assign(
    Column1 = pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'], errors='coerce'))
 .dropna(subset='Column1'))
```

---

A more concise solution has been suggested by @Corralien (to whom I thank):

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

---

Output:

```
   Column1 Column2
2      1.0    Text
3    -15.0   13333
5    354.0    Test
```

Comment: This definitely removes the text columns. I should have been more clear in my question, but I have other columns of data in the rows. Your current solution removes all columns and rows that are text in Column1.

Comment: Could you edit your question accordingly, @Mark?

Comment: Thanks, @Corralien, for having edited my solution with a solution that answers the OP problem. Unfortunately, I did not notice your edit before editing it myself with another solution. Your approach is more concise than mine though.